# Check All Checkbox items on DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, checkbox

Here's the scenario.

I have `checkbox`(Name:"Check All" ID:chkItems) and `datagridview`. And when I click on this checkbox, all checkboxes on the `datagridview` will also be checked.

I've also added the checkbox column on the grid.

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn CheckboxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
CheckboxColumn.Width = 20;
GridView1.Columns.Add(CheckboxColumn);
```

Here is the code behind of the checkbox. There is a problem on the `row.Cell`

```
private void chkItems_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = e.row.Cells(0);
        if (chk.Selected == false)
        {
            row.Cells(0).Value = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) row.Cells[0];
```

instead of

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = e.row.Cell(0);
```

***EDIT:***I think you really want to do this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
       DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) row.Cells[0];
       chk.Value = !(chk.Value == null ? false : (bool) chk.Value); //because chk.Value is initialy null
}
```

Comment: when i tried this one, DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = row.Cells[0]; there is still error on row.cells[0];

Comment: check the edit, you need to cast the Cell to DataGridViewCheckBoxCell

Comment: there's error on the checkbox column that i created // Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageCell' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxCell'.

Comment: What is the index of the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn in your datagridview?

Comment: i've added this column DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn CheckboxColumn = new DataGridView CheckBoxColumn();
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            CheckboxColumn.Width = 20;
            GridView1.Columns.Add(CheckboxColumn);

Comment: Thanks! I'm done with it. but there's a problem. there's no chk.Checked it chk.Selected. that's why it's only selecting the item. how can i check the checkbox?

Comment: I see it from the code you posted but there is also some other column in you dataGridView that is making problems

Comment: I've posted that edit already, load it. You should access chk.Value

Comment: I used this answer but another one was a little more helpful in case you need to select all checkboxes after some user input that might set a checkbox cell into edit mode. In that case, this answer leaves the edit mode cells as they are.

Replace `chk.Value !=...` in the answer about with this:`chk.Value = !(chk.EditedFormattedValue.ToString() == "false" ? false : (bool)chk.EditedFormattedValue);` and you should be in good shape.

Comment: It also helps to set the `dgv.DefaultCell = null;`

Answer (score 3):

```
    private void setCheckBoxInDataGrid(DataGridView dgv, int pos, bool isChecked)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
        {
            dgv.Rows[i].DataGridView[pos, i].Value = isChecked;
        }
    }
```

This is how I did it

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
      row.Cells[0].Value = row.Cells[0].Value == false ? true : false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with providing a default state to the `checkboxes of datagridview` on your own i.e either True or False[Do not assign a null state] state(Reason for doing this would be explained in the latter).

Which could be done by the following code,(type in this code when you search for results to be viewed in `DataGridView`)
`dgv` is the object of the `DataGridView` that you are using.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
     dgv.Rows[i].DataGridView[0, i].Value = true;
}
```

Where `DataGridView[0, i]` indicates 0th column ith row
The Reason for doing this is,On load the checkbox is by default in a `null` state. The code isn't comparing for `null` state(Creating a object null reference exception). So, once when u assign it a state either a false or true . It can never undergo into `null` state.
Type in the following code inside the button_click_event using which you are going to check

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount-1; i++)
{
    if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() != "")
    {
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = false;
    }
    else
    {
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = true;
    }
}
```

It Worked for me, I hope it does for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to select all checkbox or select it mutuality and calculate some value...so wrote this code that's maybe helpful.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in DGDoc.Rows)
{
    if (item.Cells[0].Value == null)
        item.Cells[0].Value = "True";
    if (bool.Parse(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
    {
        item.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(241, 215, 215);
        strIDs += "," + item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        intSumPrice += Int64.Parse(item.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
        intSumTax += Int64.Parse(item.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
        intSumPay += Int64.Parse(item.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        item.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
    }
}
DGDoc.EndEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Create new button.

2- You can use the following code when click checkAll button

3- when click the button it will check all checkboxes in datagridview and when click again it will uncheck all boxes.

```
private void btncheckall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvResult.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells[0].Value = row.Cells[0].Value == null ? false : !(bool)row.Cells[0].Value;
            }
        }
```

Note: in some cases you have to click in datagridview first then click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all cells like this:

```
private void CheckAllCheckboxItemsOnDataGridView(int columnIndex)
{ 
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgFiles.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[columnIndex];

        cell.Value = !(cell.Value == null ? false : (bool)cell.Value); 
    }
}
```

You can use method in CheckedChanged event like this:

```
private void chkItems_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAllCheckboxItemsOnDataGridView(columnIndex: 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version, which allows a more natural behavior I'd say; if one of the checkboxes is ticked, all checkboxes are ticked as well when selecting all.

How it'll be usefull to you :)

```
private void BtnSelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Boolean> chkList = new List<Boolean>();
        bool ticked = false;
    
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
            chkList.Add((bool)chk.Value);
        }
    
        if (!chkList.Contains(true))
        {
            ticked = true;
        }
        else if (!chkList.Contains(false))
        {
            ticked = false;
        } else
        {
            ticked = true;
        }
    
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
            chk.Value = ticked;
        }
    }
```