# Can't change the default value of checkbox in DataGridView (Windows Form Application)

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I'm trying to check checkboxes for all rows as default in DataGridView. But the code below is not working.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sqlDA.Fill(dt);
dgvTeacherClasses.DataSource = dt;

DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkCell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
{
    ValueType = typeof(bool),
    Name = "check",
    HeaderText = ""
};

dgvTeacherClasses.Columns.Add(checkCell);

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTeacherClasses.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[checkCell.Name].Value = true;
}
```

Checkboxes are still remain unchecked. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show your table schema and data adapter?

Comment: @Alex: I solved it, thank you.

Comment: It is good that you were able to find an answer to your question.  Rather than post it as an edit to your question, it is good practice to post it as an answer that you can accept.  This will close your question as solved rather than leave it appearing unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32365172/6664548

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sqlDA.Fill(dt);
dgvTeacherClasses.DataSource = dt;
dt.Columns.Add("checkCell", typeof(bool));

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTeacherClasses.Rows)
{
    row.Cells["checkCell"].Value = true;
}
```